# Is a forEach in redux reducer an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, anti-patterns, redux-reducers

I have a forEach loop which checks if a certain attribute of data coming in includes '/' if it does im replace the '/' with '-', i was wondering if that is valid redux code or im creating some sort of anti-pattern code right here.

```
case actions.GET_PRODUCTS: {
      const data = { ...payload };

      data.forEach(item => {
        item.options.forEach(option => {
          if (option.includes('/')) {
            option.cleanVersion = option.replace('/', '-');
          }
        });
      });

      return {
        ...state,
        items: data,
      };
    }
```

Or could i use something along the lines of **normalizr** to handle this? and if so an example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A forEach in a reducer is perfectly fine.

You should be aware though that you are writing a style of Redux in genral that is outdated by years. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPEs, immutable reducer logic, createStore or connect.

As a result, it's 1/4 of the code and much less prone to errors.

You can read up on modern Redux by following [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).